# Is "He was shot in the street" ambiguous?

Tags: ambiguity, phrasal-verbs, meaning

I'd say both of these uses of "he was shot" make sense:

1. "How did he die?" -- "He was shot in the street" [meaning shot dead]
2. "He was shot in the street, but luckily the bullet only hit his foot." [meaning shot at -- there was a bullet coming his way]

Would you agree?

And what would you think of a headline "He was shot in the street". Is the man dead or was he just 'shot at'?

Comment: If he was shot, he was hit, not merely shot at.  "Shot" doesn't give any indication whether the injury was fatal.  Headlines tend to use "He was killed" or "He was shot dead" or something that also specifically mentions death by the gunshot wound, if that is the case.  I don't assume the gunshot wound was fatal if the headline only states "He was shot in the street".

Comment: I would have to concur with @Kristina Lopez, "He was shot in the street," is an ambiguous statement. Though when I hear "shot" I usually assume that the bullet (or whatever) hit its mark.

Comment: So we have shot dead, shot (hit him but he lives), and shot at (we don't know if it hit him) ?

Comment: If the question is: How did he DIE? And the answer is: He was shot in the street. The context is enough to conclude he was shot dead. In that case, one needn't say: shot dead. Obviously, though, a HEADLINE would NOT read: He was shot in the street. That is not headline STYLE as it is a full sentence but also does not convey the fact the man died. {sorry, I'm feeling quite impatient with this).

Comment: @R3D Yes. I think *He was shot* does imply that he was hit. Otherwise it would be *He was shot at*. But as Kristina points out, saying *he was shot* does not tell us whether it was fatal or not.

Comment: Nowadays, considering what's been happening recently in the US, if the headline were simply:  *25-year-old shot by police* we can be pretty certain the man is dead. I agree with @Lambie that the OP's headline is atypical and incomplete. It is almost meaningless.

Comment: @Mari-LouA We can even have fair odds on guessing his race...

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't know about that. The headlines I've seen today are pretty clear about whether people are dead or not: ["Dallas Shooting Leaves 5 Police Officers Dead; Suspect Is Killed" -The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/07/09/us/dallas-police-shooting.html?_r=0) I think if it just says "he was shot" I would assume the victim was alive.

Comment: "He was shot in the street" is not ambiguous, which is the OP's question. It means he was hit by a bullet in the street. OP seems to think "shot" sometimes means "shot dead". But "shot" does not mean "shot dead". "Shot dead" means "shot dead".

Comment: @NoMoreSecrets it appears that whenever firearms are involved in a shootout, someone gets killed, as the number of mass killings and the death toll, due to guns, continue to rise in the US; the words "shot (at)" will, one day,  be synonymous with death. The term *wounded* will be used instead, e.g. *25-year-old wounded by police* means the person was shot but has not deceased.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Your comment received 13 upvotes. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Altho' "wounded by police" might clearly imply "shot" in some circumstances, it could be a result of being hit by a baton. I don't think it necessarily imply 'shot'.

Comment: @TrevorD USA, US cops. And I know some British officers now carry arms, but in the US it is ubiquitous.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't see any evidence of your view in news headlines. Maybe people do what you're describing in informal utterances, such as text messages. But reporters use precise language. It's part of the job.

Comment: 2Mari-Lou A--I wouldn't take a headline "25-year-old shot by police" to mean that the person died; quite the contrary.  If he had died, the headline would have said "killed".

Comment: Well I didn't post it as an answer, it was a bitter and sad remark in view of recent tragic events. My heart aches for all those who have been killed needlessly. Let me repeat this once again, it was a **comment**, but I feel there is an element of truth in what I said. I do not wish to offend anyone. I also said I agreed with Lambie's analysis.

Answer (score 4):

> And what would you think of a headline "He was shot in the street". Is
>   the man dead or was he just 'shot at'?

Neither.  "He was shot in the street" only means he was shot.  There's no ambiguity.  It means a bullet from a gun struck him.  It doesn't mean that the bullet missed him.  It also doesn't mean he was shot dead.  It makes no implication about whether the bullet killed him or not.  All it means is that he was struck by a bullet somewhere on his person.

It'd be no different than if you were to say, "He was stabbed in the street."  It's not ambiguous.  It means that someone with a sharp object lacerated him to penetrate his person with it. It doesn't mean he was stabbed to death.  It doesn't mean that someone tried to stab him and missed.  It just means that he was stabbed.

Comment: I know it is an off-topic comment, but are you Benjamin Harman that I know?

Comment: Although "in the street" can have a connotation somewhat above/beyond merely identifying a locale.  In the right context it suggests that something like gang warfare or drug dealing was involved.  For instance, if he was shot by a jealous husband one would be less inclined to qualify it with "in the street".

Comment: @Rathony - The one and only.  I haven't been on in a long while.  I only came on because I posted a grammar question.  I don't know what happened to my old account.  I couldn't remember the user name.  So this is a new account.

Comment: Ha ha. I knew it. Welcome back to ELU and you have to promise you will never leave it again. You can flag your own answer and ask moderators to help. Your account is here!!!

Comment: @Rathony - Flag my own account?  You mean this one?  Because I don't know what the other one is.  Plus, I don't know how to flag my own account anyway.  Pretty pathetic, huh?

Comment: Don't you see **flag** button at the bottom? When you click on it, you will see **in need of moderator intervention**. You can write there "I am [B. Harman](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/115101/benjamin-harman) and I can't log on my old account because XYZ". Good luck.

Comment: @Rathony - Thanks.  And thanks for the link to my old account.  I couldn't even find that.  I still don't see where I can flag my own account, though.  I think it may be something this account doesn't have enough points for yet, but now that I have my old account, I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman You are welcome. You need to flag this **answer**, not an **account**. You can visit the link and merge the accounts. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts if you successfully log on to the old account. If you can't, you need to seek a moderator's help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm nothing if not obedient @Rathony. :-)

Here's my comment, copied into an answer...

> If he was shot, he was hit, not merely shot at. "Shot" doesn't give
>   any indication whether the injury was fatal.
>
> Headlines tend to use "He was killed" or "He was shot dead" or
>   something that also specifically mentions death by the gunshot wound,
>   if that is the case. I don't assume the gunshot wound was fatal if the
>   headline only states "He was shot in the street".

Answer (score -3):

Three problems with this sentence. 
First, unclear antecedent. Who is "he?"
Second, "was shot" is in the passive voice.
Third, unless "the street" is a part of "his" body, then you need to split this sentence or rearrange it.
Example: "The kidnapper" (Now we know who "he" is) ran into the street (now we know where he was), where he was shot (now we know what happened, but there's still that nagging passive voice).

Or: "While the kidnapper stood in the street, police shot him."

Comment: You know, the passive voice is not itself an error (or even poor form, in this particular sentence).

Comment: First, we do not need an antecedent, nor need to know who "he" is, in order to interpret the sentence. Second, you fail to explain why "was shot" being in the passive voice is 'a problem'. If we do not know who did the shooting (or if it's irrelevant), the passive voice is quite acceptable . In some circumstances, your third 'problem' *might* be an issue, but we all know what "in the street" means, and that "the street" is not part of the body! So there is no ambiguity! Finally, you haven't actually answered the Q of whether there is any ambiguity.

Comment: Laurence Sterne had a good deal of fun with this type of ambiguity in *Tristram Shandy.* Having heard that Uncle Toby had been wounded in the groin at the battle of Naumur, and contemplating marriage with him, the Widow Wadman wants to know if he is disabled sexually, so she asks him exactly where he was wounded. He takes that to mean where on the battlefield, amid the fortifications of Naumur, and he actually builds an extensive model of those fortifications in an effort to answer her question.